# ScriptManager, Page, static methods... how do I get the current ScriptManager without Page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, scriptmanager

I'm trying to extend `ScriptManager` to simplify dealing with resources that have multiple resource files (e.g. more than one script file as well as css). The goal is that I will be able to add a single `ScriptReference` to `Scripts` and have it load more than one resource related to that reference name.

What I'm getting stuck on is, how does your basic `ScriptManager` know what to do with stuff when when using static methods that do not include a `Page` parameter? For example:

```
ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("someName", new
   ScriptResourceDefinition { Path="/script/somescript.js"});
```

This adds a definition to (I guess) whatever the active script manager is for the page that's running when you call it. But unlike the old-school methods, like `RegisterClientScriptBlock` there is no parameter passed that identifies the page. But this stuff must get stored in the `ScriptManager` object, no? So how does it know?

I could always get a reference to the active one with this:

`ScriptManager.GetCurrent(page);`

but ideally, I would create new methods that work exactly like Microsoft's. I can't figure out how I could implement something like

```
ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition(string name,
    ScriptResourceDefinition definition,
    ResourceType type)
```

that could figure out the object instance to add the stuff into without having to add a Page parameter. Somehow they're doing it... how can I?

Comment: Why you try to go from script manager and not create a simple handler and read the files by your self, do the same job with your code and you can have a total full control of them. (minified them, clear them etc)

Comment: I already have something like that, which is how I ended up here. But I really want to integrate it with ScriptManager because it has some very useful features (like determining which version to use for debug/release, CDN, etc), so I see no reason to reinvent the wheel for all that functionality.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get the page reference through `(Page)(HttpContext.Current.Handler)` even in a static context.

Comment: I did not know this. Thanks. Been crunching through my script manager and figured it all out by looking at MS' source, in the end I don't actually need to reference it at all but this answers my question. I did figure out what MS does, though, the ScriptResourceDefinition static methods do not have a page context at all. (ScriptResourceDefintion is a static object with no context).